# Count How many times an item appears in relation to a value from another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have 2 worksheets, what I want to achieve is to count how many times an item in column B appears if column A has a value of "1" on it.

Worksheet 1
Column A (A2=1, A4=1, A7=1, A10=1, A13=1, A14=1, A15=1, A17=1, A18=1

Column B (B1= John Doe, B2= Philip Seymour, B3= Anthony Jones, B4= Thomas Moore, B5= Lindsey Lohan, B6= Rudy Duterte, B7= Philip Seymour, B8= Anthony Jones, B9= John Doe, B10= Philip Seymour, B11= Anthony Jones, B12= Thomas Moore, B13=Lindsey Lohan, B14= Rudy Duterte, B15= Anthony Jones, B16= John Doe, B17= Rudy Duterte

the result will be reflected in worksheet two like this

John Doe = 3
Philip Seymour = 1
Anthony Jones = 1
Thomas Moore = 1
Lindsey Lohan = 1
Rudy Duterte = 3

Comment: do you need all those values in one cell, or is it ok to have them in separate ones? Just to sum up 1-s easiest way is to use a pivot table.

Comment: The results that you show in your question don't match your description of the problem (and your input data).  Part of the discrepancy might be that your Column `A` data go from row 2 to row 18, but your Column `B` data go from row 1 to row 17.

Answer (score 0):

Found this and got the result I wanted:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('2015'!$B$2:$B$19=Count!A2)*('2015'!$A$2:$A$19=1))
```